# How to Moq lazy interface in nunit?

Tags: c#, interface, nunit, lazy-loading, moq

#### The system under test

```
public class AddDateRangeSaga : IDistributedSaga<AddDateRangeRequestModel, AddDateRangeResponseModel>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// AddDateRangeAr Inject
    /// </summary>
    public readonly Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr> _addDateRangesAr;

    /// <summary>
    /// For log and exception handling
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IApiRequestHandler _reqHandler;

    public AddDateRangeSaga(IApiRequestHandler reqHandler
        , Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr> addDateRangesAr)
    {
        _reqHandler = reqHandler;
        _addDateRangesAr = addDateRangesAr;
    }
    public async Task<AddDateRangeResponseModel> Execute(AddDateRangeRequestModel request)
    {
        return await _addDateRangesAr.Value.AddDateRange(request);
    }
}
```

#### The test case

```
public class AddDateRangeSagaTests
{
    private Mock<IApiRequestHandler> _mockApiRequestHandler;
    public Mock<Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr>> _addDateRangesAr;
    private MockRepository mockRepository;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _mockApiRequestHandler = mockRepository.Create<IApiRequestHandler>();
        _addDateRangesAr = mockRepository.Create<Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr>>();
    }

    private AddDateRangeSaga CreateAddDateRangeSagaTests()
    {
        return new AddDateRangeSaga(this._mockApiRequestHandler.Object, _addDateRangesAr.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task AddDateRangeSaga_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
    {
        //Arrange
        var addDateRangeAr = this.CreateAddDateRangeSagaTests();
        AddDateRangeRequestModel addDateRangeRequestModel = new AddDateRangeRequestModel();
        AddDateRangeResponseModel addDateRangeResponseModel = new AddDateRangeResponseModel();
        _addDateRangesAr.Setup(x => x.Value.AddDateRange(addDateRangeRequestModel)).ReturnsAsync(addDateRangeResponseModel);
       
        var dd = addDateRangeAr.Execute(addDateRangeRequestModel);
        
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1,1); //dummy

    }
}
```

#### Received error during execution

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Value
> Non-overridable members (here: Lazy.get_Value) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

#### Problem

I am not able to figure out the exact issue with lazy moq. Can someone help me to figure out the issue?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940102/mock-lazy-interface-with-moq) should solve your problem. Essentially, Moq can only mock interfaces or virtual methods. You don't need to mock the whole lazy object, just `IAddDateRangeAr` and initialize Lazy with a func to the mocked object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me share with you the revised version of your test then the explanation.

```
public class AddDateRangeSagaTests
{
    private Mock<IApiRequestHandler> apiRequestHandlerMock;
    private Mock<IAddDateRangeAr> addDateRangesArMock;
    private MockRepository mockRepository;
    
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
        apiRequestHandlerMock = mockRepository.Create<IApiRequestHandler>();
        addDateRangesArMock = mockRepository.Create<IAddDateRangeAr>();
    }

    private AddDateRangeSaga CreateAddDateRangeSagaTests()
    {
        var lazyAddDateRangesAr = new Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr>(() => addDateRangesArMock.Object);
        return new AddDateRangeSaga(apiRequestHandlerMock.Object, lazyAddDateRangesAr);
    }
    
    [Test]
    public async Task AddDateRangeSaga_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
    {
        //Arrange
        var sut = this.CreateAddDateRangeSagaTests();
        addDateRangesArMock
          .Setup(x => x.AddDateRange(It.IsAny<AddDateRangeRequestModel>()))
          .ReturnsAsync(new AddDateRangeResponseModel());

        //Act
        var response = await sut.Execute(addDateRangeRequestModel);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(response);
    }
}
```

- I've changed your `_addDateRangesAr` field to `addDateRangesArMock`

  - Here we are mocking the interface itself not the Lazy container
  - I've changed the visibility as well from `public` to `private` because this field should not be accessed by any other class
- I've changed the name of `_mockApiRequestHandler` field to `apiRequestHandlerMock` to avoid using `_` prefixes
- Inside the `CreateAddDateRangeSagaTests` I've initialized a `Lazy<IAddDateRangeAr>` which will return the mocked `IAddDateRangeAr` whenever it's first accessed
- I've simplified the mock setup and made it more generic

  - from `.AddDateRange(addDateRangeRequestModel)`
  - to `.AddDateRange(It.IsAny<AddDateRangeRequestModel>())`
- I've called the `Execute` with `await` to be able to examine the response
- I've used a simple null check to make sure it works as expected